# Accessing Construct 2 generated JavasScript through custom JS

Tags: javascript, php, variables, scope, construct-2

I have a game built with Construct2 Engine, I'd like to get the value of the game user's score using external JavaScript .. Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `c2_callFunction` to get or set value directly from construct.

For example `alert(c2_callFunction("get_score"));`

and in your construct2 project:

[image: Construct 2]